# Remove a specific DIV in a row by its ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using Django and have several Bootstrap cards on my page like the structure below, and I am trying to remove one div on click (X on my `<a>`)

```
<row>
  <col-sm-3 id="{{ topic.pk }}">
    <card>
      <...><a href="" class="remove" data-id="{{ topic.pk }}">X</a></> #ID here is 1
    </>
  </>
  <col-sm-3 id="{{ topic.pk }}">
    <card>
      <...><a href="" class="remove" data-id="{{ topic.pk }}">X</a></> #ID here is 2
    </>
  </>
</>
```

```js
$(function(){
  $('a.remove').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    var id = $this.data('id');
    $.get('/messages/delete/'+id, {}, function(response) {
      $this.parent().fadeOut(300, function(){
        $(this).remove();
      });
    });
  });
});
```

The on click doesn't work. Debugging the code:

> 127.0.0.1:8000/messages/delete/1 404 NOT FOUND

I understand, the "a" has a connection to my function. What I don't understand, whats the purpose of

```
$.get('/messages/delete/'+id, {}, function(response)?
```

I just want the Card-Div to be removed.
How can I change my code to make it work? Any input appreciated.

Comment: Are you also deleting a row from a database? Because it's an ajax call, also you should never use GET in this case, POST or DELETE is the way to go

Comment: The element isn't being removed because the callback is only executed when the AJAX request is successful. You're getting a 404 response, so that's not happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending my comment.

This part:

```
$.get('/messages/delete/'+id, {}, function(response) { ... });
```

is an AJAX call (that also uses the GET HTTP method - and it should use either POST or DELETE) that sends a request to the specified route. One could guess that it's connected to a delete method, to remove a row with specified ID from a database.

Your error comes up, because you don't have that route set up.

This part:

```
$this.parent().fadeOut(300, function(){$(this).remove()
```

is the one that actually removes the HTML element from the page. In your current code it's called in a callback function from the AJAX request (that never succeeds), therefore it never fires.

If you only want to remove the card element from the html, you should go with:

```
$(function(){
  $('a.remove').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('card').remove();
  });
});
```

If you actually want to remove a row from a table in your database that would require you setting up a route and a method in the backend (Django in your case), and then removing it in the frontend after a successful request.

Comment: Based on your old comment, I did something like this: $(function(){
   $('a.remove').on('click', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var $this = $(this);
      var id = '"#' + $this.data('id') + '"';
      $(id).remove();
   });
}); - which results in Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: "#8". Your last piece of code does nothing (not even an error) - I wont say I am stupid, but I have REAL problems which JavaScript. Thank you for your input anyway

Comment: try $('#' + $(this).data('id')).remove();